# CountUp no reset when user refresh page using localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a CountUp script which i have specified the number it should start from and where it should stop counting. This works fine, however i have tried to use localStorage.setItem to save the progress so that when user refreshes the page or leaves the page and returns, the counter doesn't refresh but keeps running. It doesn't seem to work for me, admittedly i am still trying to struggle with Javascript being a newbie. Your help will be highly appreciated, thanks. Below is my Code

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
function countUp() {
  var countEl = document.querySelector('.counter');
  var countBar = document.querySelector('.progress-bar');
  var x = 1;
  var y = countEl.dataset.to;
  var z = countBar.dataset.to;
  
  function addNum() {
    countEl.innerHTML = x;
    x += 1;
    if (x > y && x > z) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      toggleBtn.classList.remove('hidden');
    }
  }
  
  var timer = window.setInterval(addNum, 800);
  localStorage.setItem("addNum", counter);
  
  toggleBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    countUp();
    toggleBtn.classList.add('hidden');
  });
}
countUp();</script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script></head>
<body onload=countUp();>
  <div class="counter" data-from="0" data-to="100"></div>
  <div class="progress-bar"  data-from="0" data-to="100"></div>
```

Thanks in anticipation of a right pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `var x` line to:

```
var x = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('lastCount')) - 1 || 1;
```

Change `addNum()` function to:

```
function addNum() {
  countEl.innerHTML = x;
  x += 1;
  if (x > y && x > z) {
    clearInterval(timer);
    toggleBtn.classList.remove('hidden');
  }
  localStorage.setItem('lastCount', x);
}
```

*https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage*

---

##### EDIT: COUNT IN BACKGROUND

This is not an 'actual' counting in the background. The idea here is to differentiate between the latest and last timestamp.

###### 1. Change your `var x` line to:

```
var x = getCounter();
```

###### 2. Add a new function. `getCounter()`:

```
function getCounter() {
  if(localStorage.getItem('lastCount')) {
    let counter = (Math.floor(Date.now() /1000) - parseInt(localStorage.getItem('lastTimestamp'))) + parseInt(localStorage.getItem('lastCount'));
    return (counter > 100) ? 100: counter 
  } 
  return 1;
}
```

> *Note: The counter will not exceed 100. `data-to="100"`*

###### 3. Append this code to `addNum()`:

```
localStorage.setItem('lastCount', x);
localStorage.setItem('lastTimestamp', Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000));
```

Comment: Although i accepted this answer already but i noticed that when you leave the page and come back, it starts from where it stopped. The idea of counting in background is defeated.